# How to use two comparative adjectives in a row?

Tags: comparatives

What is the right way to use two comparisons in a row?

> "He wants to marry somebody more beautiful and rich."
>   "He wants to marry somebody more beautiful and richer."

I was able to find examples of using both options, and now I'm not sure what is right.

Comment: They're both "right" ... it just depends on what you want to say. If you want to avoid ambiguity, use a comparative complement: "more beautiful and rich *than he is*."

Comment: It would sound better if you reversed the adjectives: *He wants to marry somebody **richer and more beautiful**.*